# About JQuery.Callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you are familiar with jquery inner workings you probably will understand lines of codes:

```
var tuples = [
                // action, add listener, listener list, final state
                [ "resolve", "done", jQuery.Callbacks("once memory"), "resolved" ],
                [ "reject", "fail", jQuery.Callbacks("once memory"), "rejected" ],
                [ "notify", "progress", jQuery.Callbacks("memory") ]
            ]

               //some codes

jQuery.each( tuples, function( i, tuple ) {
    var list = tuple[ 2 ],
        stateString = tuple[ 3 ];

    // promise[ done | fail | progress ] = list.add
    promise[ tuple[1] ] = list.add;

    // Handle state
    if ( stateString ) {
        list.add(function() {
            // state = [ resolved | rejected ]
            state = stateString;

        // [ reject_list | resolve_list ].disable; progress_list.lock
        }, tuples[ i ^ 1 ][ 2 ].disable, tuples[ 2 ][ 2 ].lock );
    }

    // deferred[ resolve | reject | notify ]
    deferred[ tuple[0] ] = function() {
        deferred[ tuple[0] + "With" ]( this === deferred ? promise : this, arguments );
        return this;
    };
    deferred[ tuple[0] + "With" ] = list.fireWith; 
});
```

I noticed that when `JQuery.Callbacks` was called in the `Jquery.Deferred` function to return its `self` object.

```
 deferred.resolveWith( document, [ jQuery ] ) calls a fireWith: function(     context, args ) {
    if ( list && ( !fired || stack ) ) {
        args = args || [];
        args = [ context, args.slice ? args.slice() : args ];
        if ( firing ) {
            stack.push( args ); 
        } else {
            fire( args ); // notice that fire is called in here
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

from the `self` object which in turn calls `fire()` from the `jquery.Callbacks` function.

My question really is how could `fire()` in `resolveWith` catch an empty list from `jquery.Callbacks('memory')` on the third call.

using this example i tried to explain what i am trying to say here;

```
 var grtObj={};
     vals =jQuery.Callbacks("once memory");// first call

        function toAdd(){};
        vals.add(toAdd);
        grtObj['practice'] = vals.fireWith;
        console.log(grtObj);
        //runnig grtObj['practice']() here caught val.fireWith;

    valu = jQuery.Callbacks("once memory"); //run 2
        function duff(){};
        valu.add(duff);
        grtObj['act'] = valu.fireWith;

     grtObj['practice'](); //caugth  function duff() added to the list with valu.add instead of the toadd function that was added when grtObj['practice'] = vals.fireWith was defined.

console.log(valu.fireWith==vals.fireWith)//false
console.log(grtObj.practice==grtObj.act)//false//-->
```

How can `grtObj['practice']()` fetch function `duff()`

```
       // grtObj.practice() caught this valu.fireWith // since the different calls of jQuery.Callbacks does not return to the same variable, it surprises me how  grtObj.practice could fetch function duffA() that was added from the second call. It does not matter whether grtObj['act'] = valu.fireWith was set or not.
```

Can anyone help me explain this?

Comment: thanks Barmer for the edt

Comment: no one has tried to answer this?